# How to dynamically create IQueryable<T> from list of column names

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, iqueryable

I have 2 entities, Country and City. A Country can have many cities. 
I want to achieve the following:

```
IQueryable<Country> query =
    myContext.Countries
             .Select(co => new Country
                 {
                     Id = co.Id,
                     Name = co.Name,
                     Cities = co.Cities.Select(c => new City { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name })
                 })
             .AsQueryable();
```

But with a function accepting an array of property names like

```
string[] columns = new string[] { "Id", "Name", "Cities.Name" }
```

So far I tried to modify the following function seen on this platform, but it throw an exception on "Cities.Name" not belonging to Country entity.

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TResult>(this IQueryable source, string[] columns)
{
    var sourceType = source.ElementType;
    var resultType = typeof(TResult);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "e");
    var bindings = columns.Select(column => Expression.Bind(resultType.GetProperty(column), Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, column)));
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(resultType), bindings);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(
        Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", new Type[] { sourceType, resultType },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector)));
}
```

Call:

```
IQueryable<Country> query = _hotelContext.Countries.Select<Country>(new string[] { "Id", "Name", "Cities.Name" });

return await query.ToListAsync();
```

Please help, very desperate for an answer.
Cheers

Comment: I think you're supposed to modify the expression so that it detects the need for the subquery and automatically constructs it. Man, that is a tough assignment.

Comment: Why do u need a  generic `Select<T>` method?

Comment: Adbul Samad, one can argue that the Select<T> is not strictly necessary, but the end goal is to be able to get an IQueryable from a list of column names

Comment: I get this error `'Cities.Name' is not a member of type 'UserQuery+Country'
` using your code. The type has changed hence it is unable to find `Cities.Name` on it

Comment: Abdul Samad, this is the error I get. I know that i have to refine the function to address this need.

Comment: See [DynamicLINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), [ExpressionTrees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries).